# QGIS Georeferencer, unexpected transformation, and GCP placement

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, georeferencing

I'm trying to get the sample map which I believe to be EPSG:3112 into QGIS and georeferenced. In my screenshot, on the right is the raster in georeferencer with the points I have added. On the left is how that same raster appears now those Ground Control Points (GCPs) have been added.

**Two things are happening that I'm not sure why or what I can do about:**

- The raster is being stretched
- And the GCP's are being arranged in a parallel type grid

Both my project, and raster layer are set to EPSG:3112 and when I do the referencing I have EPSG:3112 selected as well in the transformation settings.

[image]

**Ive since tried setting these settings but no difference:**
[image]

**This is what i get with "projective" transformation** (still deformed)
[image]

This is the result after making the grid and changing on the fly to 3112, there is also pictured the settings i try for "densify geometries", when i click ok it asks for crs, and after that it i dont see anything new and the except in the layer window, except the dialog stays open and progress bar continually slides back and forth...
[image]

Comment: I think you have got the coordinates for your North Western points false. The first meridian to hit the continent is 115°, not 110°. And the next two points should be at 120°E

Comment: ok well that could explain a bit, it poor quality scan so i cant read the writing very well... just a temp map for testing while i wait for high rez version

Comment: I got the map from http://www.screen.nsw.gov.au/filming-on-nsw-indigenous-land/aboriginal-australia-map/; converted the linked pdf with Gimp to a png.

Comment: im trying again from start with a higher res image so i can read the lines better to get the right values. when i load the raster in georeferencer should i be choosing crs 3112 or 4283 ?

Comment: If you enter degrees manually, in 4283; if you grab the points from the curved grid, 3112. For the first one, try Thin plate spline. The second might give less distortion, so Projective will be enough.

Comment: thanks, i got my head around it, about the role of the two different crs's and i think my initial mistake of when makeing the points was what messed me up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have entered the GCP coordinates in degrees, probably read from the imprinted degree grid.

In that case, you have to set the CRS to EPSG:4283 (GDA94), which is the unprojected CRS for your EPSG:3112.

EPSG:3112 has metres as units, not degrees.

---

**EDIT**

Another choice of doing the georeferencing is to create a vector grid in EPSG:4283.

This is what you have to do:

- Create a text file with the extent in degrees:

> ```
> Nr,E,N
> 1,110,-10
> 2,160,-40
> ```

- Load it with `Layer -> Add delimited text layer`, choosing comma as separator, E for X and N for Y value, and EPSG:4283 as CRS. If the software does not ask for that, rightclick on the layer -> `Set CRS for layer`
- `Vector -> Research Tools - Vector grid`
- Click `Update extents from layer`
- Set parameter X to 5 (the spacing of your grid) and `Output grid as lines`
- Choose a new file name and click `OK`
- Change project CRS to EPSG:3112

You will see the meridians right in place, but the latitudes not bended.

- `Vector -> Geometry Tools -> Densify Geometry`
- Set `Vertices to add` to 49, and save the result
- Add labelling for this layer, using attribute COORD

The new grid should now look like that on your raster file.

- Load the raster file into the georeferencer, choosing EPSG:3112 for output

This is what I got with `Projective` and a residual of less than 10:

[image]

Comment: thank you ever so much for your help, i did just read the degrees off the map lines, where do i set " CRS to EPSG:4283 (GDA94)" - i tried a few spots but no luck...

Comment: In the georeferencer window, you have the tool icon, where you set the output file name, as well as transformation type and target SRS.

Comment: i just tried setting 4283 in the tool icon window, but no difference, see my screenshot above. which transformation type should i choose ? i dont really want the image changed at all ...

Comment: `Linear` will not work in your case. Try Projective or Thin Plate spline. The residual should be only a few pixels, and the red lines should be reduced to points.

Comment: i tried both those without success, ive posted a screen of projective above. i will try the other method you added in your edit. thankyou again.

Comment: so ive tried doing what you suggest in your edit, but i cant work it out: new 3112 project, add 3112 map raster, research tools->vector grid (no 100% what to do at this step) -> then what ? can you tell me what i need to do, thanks.

Comment: hi thanks again, ive posted another screen of how far i got, not all the way though, i cant get past the densify step